# This word is deep

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

- My prefix gives me the perfect job.
- My suffix gives me power over things.
- My infix makes me go in circles.
- My whole makes me lost forever.

Hint:

> If there's one thing that makes one lost forever, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DROWN

> DR is short for doctor, a lot of people desire this job.

> OWN if you own things It gives you power over them.

> ROW -- you go in circles

> If you DROWN *(a.k.a. **die**)* it could make you lost forever

> You are likely to end up deep underwater if you DROWN.

Answer (score 2):

A terrible answer but is it:

> ABANDON

Prefix:

> A BA - it is a qualification that could get you a job...

Suffix:

> ON - which I guess if you turn something on it has power?

Infix:

> BAND - which is a ring that goes in circles

Whole:

> ABANDON - well you are lost when you are abandoned!